# Unknown duplicates from querying a nested JSON

Tags: json, postgresql, jsonb

I would like to do text search in a JSON object in a table.

I have a table called Audio that is structured like below:

```
id| keyword | transcript | user_id | company_id | client_id 
-----------------------------------------------------------
```

This is the JSON data structure of `transcript`:

```
{"transcript": [
    {"duration": 2390.0, 
    "interval": [140.0, 2530.0], 
    "speaker": "Speaker_2", 
    "words": [
        {"p": 0, "s": 0, "e": 320, "c": 0.545, "w": "This"}, 
        {"p": 1, "s": 320, "e": 620, "c": 0.825, "w": "call"}, 
        {"p": 2, "s": 620, "e": 780, "c": 0.909, "w": "is"}, 
        {"p": 3, "s": 780, "e": 1010, "c": 0.853, "w": "being"}, 
        {"p": 4, "s": 1010, "e": 1250, "c": 0.814, "w": "recorded"}
        ]
    }, 
    {"duration": 4360.0, 
    "interval": [3280.0, 7640.0], 
    "speaker": "Speaker_1", 
    "words": [
        {"p": 5, "s": 5000, "e": 5020, "c": 0.079, "w": "as"},
        {"p": 6, "s": 5020, "e": 5100, "c": 0.238, "w": "a"},
        {"p": 7, "s": 5100, "e": 5409, "c": 0.689, "w": "group"},
        {"p": 8, "s": 5410, "e": 5590, "c": 0.802, "w": "called"},
        {"p": 9, "s": 5590, "e": 5870, "c": 0.834, "w": "tricks"}
        ]
    },
    ...
}
```

What I am trying to do is to do a text search in the "w" field within "words". This is the query that I tried to run:

```
WITH info_data AS (
    SELECT transcript_info->'words' AS info
    FROM Audio t, json_array_elements(transcript->'transcript') AS transcript_info)
SELECT info_item->>'w', id
FROM Audio, info_data idata, json_array_elements(idata.info) AS info_item
WHERE info_item->>'w' ilike '%this';
```

Right now I only have four columns with data and the fifth column is null. And there are five columns in total. However, I got the following result where even the column that doesn't have data results an output:

```
?column? | id 
----------+----
 This     |  2
 This     |  5
 This     |  1
 This     |  3
 This     |  4
 This     |  2
 This     |  5
```

I would love to know what the problem of my query is and whether there are more efficient way in doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you make a cartesian join between table `Audio` on the one hand and `info_data` and `info_item` on the other hand (there is an implicit lateral join between these latter two) here:

```
FROM Audio, info_data idata, json_array_elements(idata.info) AS info_item
```

You can solve this by adding `Audio.id` to the CTE and then adding `WHERE Audio.id = info_data.id`.

It is doubtful that this is the most efficient solution (CTEs rarely are). If you just want to get those rows where the word "this" is a word in the transcript, then you are most likely better off like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT id
FROM (
    SELECT id, transcript_info->'words' AS info
    FROM Audio, json_array_elements(transcript->'transcript') AS transcript_info) AS t,
    json_array_elements(info) AS words
WHERE words->>'w' ILIKE 'this';
```

Note that the `%` in the pattern string is very inefficient. Since very few words in the English language other than "this" end with the same, I have taken the liberty of removing it.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH! I was struggling for the past hours. This is a much  much better solution to what I was looking for!

Comment: do you happen to know how to resolve implicit lateral join problem within sqlalchemy? I have tried to translate your suggestion into sqlalchemy query and am running into the exact same problem. See more here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41050712/postgres-sqlalchemy-double-counting-results?noredirect=1#comment69319934_41050712

Comment: I can not help you here because I do not know SQLAlchemy. A surefire solution, however, is to wrap the above query in a view, leaving out the `WHERE` clause and adding as much other columns to the select list as necessary (`words` as a minimum). In SQLAlchemy you can then simply `SELECT` from the view and attach the `WHERE` clause. This is a solid approach that works for all DB frameworks (Hibernate, rails, etc): leave all the query complexity in the DB and do straightforward stuff in the framework.